# how to add button in label text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't know if this is applicable in iphone. I'm trying to add button inside label text. See image below.[image]

If you see there is href or anchor(web name) inside the square that I'm pointing. Can I put button inside the text? These data came from rest api. I need an advice if this applicable or possible to do that. If ever this is applicable please give me idea on how to do that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: in this place use UIButton and set titlelabelText.text

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I don't have control to edit the data. It came from the rest api. Sorry I'm new of this objective-c. If this is not applicable. I'm going to delete my post

Comment: I would use a UIWebView to display your data.

Comment: @latenitecoder so it means this is not possible in ios. Thanks anyway for your advice

Comment: The text passed through your app to get from the rest API to the label, you have the ability to edit it. Not really clear what you want to do- make the text clickable like a link in a webpage?

Comment: You need to enable the html support for your text view then you can het the click on link. and you can use the delegate method to get the click on link as well.

-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange

this is the delgate methode.

Comment: @MichaelSand yes! sorry if my post is not clear to you. I want the that link clickable and link to webpage.

Comment: @Ahsan I'm going to study first that delegate. sorry I'm noob of this.

Comment: I believe that textView delegate method only applies if the URL is visible in the text, which given the long URL, might not be what you want. I agree with @latenitecoder, using a WebView is the simplest. Make a basic html string and load it with loadHTMLString:baseURL. It's easy to find out how to do this. There's a slight performance penalty, especially in a tableView, but it's manageable and worth it, especially if you already have html style links you're trying to display. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is actually add user interaction to certain range of the string, right?

This can be easily achieved by this library [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel)

Please take a look at it and then you can dynamically set what you want to link.

Comment: yup! I going to look your library